# Kotlin databinding shared viewmodel not updating both views

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to use a shared viewmodel for an activity and a fragment displayed in the activity because both need to be updated by the viewmodel. The fragment is constantly updated using MutableLiveData, but the activity is not and I don't really understand why. For readability reasons I did cut out the layout parameters in the .xml files which are irrelevant to the problem.
My activity code looks like the following:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     private lateinit var _binding : MainActivityBinding
     private val _viewModel : MySharedViewModel by viewModels()

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         _binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity)
         _binding.viewModel = _viewModel
         _binding.lifecycleOwner = this
         ...
     }
}
```

The lifecycle owner of the binding is set, yet MutableLiveData does not seem to update the activity.
In the activity layout file is the following:

```
<layout>
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.customApp.viewModels.MySharedViewModel" />
</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalTime"
            android:text="@{viewModel.topBarText}"
            .../>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    .../>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    .../>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So I have the topbar with the text view that always shall show the text, the bottom navigation view as tabbar and the fragment container view that contains the fragments.

The fragment code is:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    private val _viewModel : MySharedViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var _binding : FirstFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.first_fragment, container, false)
        _binding.viewModel = _viewModel
        _binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        return _binding.root
    }
}
```

Also here the lifecycleowner is set for the binding and in the fragment layout it is bound to the viewmodel:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.customApp.viewModels.MySharedViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <TextView
            ...
            android:text="@{viewModel.fragmentText}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.startIteration()}"
            .../>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And in my viewmodel I simply update texts that shall be displayed:

```
class MySharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var topBarText : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>("Hi")
    var fragmentText : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>("There")

    private val stringsForTop = arrayOf("Hi","How", "You")
    private val stringsForFragment = arrayOf("There","Are", "?")
    private var index = 0

    fun startIteration() {
        kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer(initialDelay = 1L, period = 1000L) {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                topBarText.value = stringsForTop[index]
                fragmentText.value = stringsForFragment[index]
                index++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now while the fragment text is updated, the text in the top bar is not updated and always just displays "Hi". I have the feeling, that the activity as lifecycleobserver for the view model is overwritten when the fragment is initialized and its viewLifecycleOwner is bound to the view model.
Am I missing something or is there another way to register both, activity and fragment with their lifecycleowners, at the viewmodel? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `by viewmodels<>()` in Fragment, it will create new instance of `ViewModel` coupled to `Fragment` life cycle. if you want same instance of `ViewModel` as it is `Activity` use by `activityViewModels<>()`, try below code in `Fragment`

```
private val _viewModel : MySharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: Will try and let you know if it worked :) thanks for the hint!

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! Would not have guessed that in ages.